# About earning the hat that has 2 hearts

Tags: support, bounties, winter-bash

I'm referring to this hat

[image]

Just to clarify, we have to start a bounty (no matter how many points, right?) on somebody else question (answers too?) at least 7 to 1 day(s) after the last day of hats, which is 2st January and so on the seventh day we award the bounty, at what time exactly?

Also I'd like to know why you designed this to be only one day on our gravatars?

Why not more days?

Thank you

Comment: The [Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/09/tis-the-season-for-hats-join-us-for-winter-bash-2019/) says that the 1st is the last day, so I'd start the bounty 5 to 1 days before; so you could award it on the 1st (or the 2nd if there's a misunderstanding). You get the hat for one day, it increases your totals, most hats ***might*** win a prize. **But** *this* is a comment, an actual answer would have to come from an employee.

Comment: @Rob On the https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/ says the last day is [January 2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfwJ4.png)

Comment: @Rob why you'd star the bounty 5 to 1 days before? should not be 7 to 1?

Comment: 1st comment, 1st sentence.